# Extracting i-th column from a tab separated text file in python

Tags: python

Say, I have a text file like this

```
John 32 Britain Marry Sunny
Britney 21 India Angel Cloudy
Jack 22 UK Becky Snowy
Jill 43 United States of America Bill Cloudy
Amy 31 South Africa Claudey Sunny
```

The data is tab separated. I want to extract the 3rd column which has the country names in a text file

```
Britain
India
UK
United States of America
South Africa
```

How to do this using python? Any help will be great. :)

Comment: Iterate through the lines of the text file, use `str.split` or the `csv` module to retrieve the items the line consists of and store the third item in a list.

Comment: share a testable content which have real tab-formatting

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post [mre] of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `csv` module from the standard library. Example implementation:

```
import csv

rows = []
with open(PATH_TO_CSV) as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t"):
        rows.append(row)

countries = [row[2] for row in rows]
```